# How to define python array with different spacing in different regions?

Tags: python, differential-equations

I want to define a python array in the range `(1,10.e10)`which I will use to solve a differential equation using `odeint`. I need different spacing in different ranges. During the initial range, I need closely spaced points, while I can do well with sparsely spaced points in the intermediate and late-time regions. What I mean is that I want to define **t**(the integration variable) such that

```
t=linspace(1,100,100000)
 =linspace(101,1000,1000)
 =linspace(1001,10e10,100)
```

How should I do that?

Comment: Maybe [numpy.concatenate()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.4/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html)?

Comment: @jbndlr, yes it works, Thanks.